# Why Jetpack Compose AppBar overlaps its shadow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, appbar

I want AppBar to display default shadow below bottom edge but appbar clips its shadow for some reason:

[image: App bar without shadow]

View hierarchy captured from LayoutInspector:

[image: 2]

My code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = Color.Cyan,
                ) {
                    Box {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = { Text("AppBar title") }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why AppBar shadow behave like this? Am I using it incorrectly? How can I fix this?

**UPD**:
My bad - shadow works as expected. I just didn't check it properly. Default shadow is very hard to detect visually:

[image: Proof of a correctly working shadow]

Comment: Try changing the elevation parameter to some value other than the default (which is 4 dp). Try setting it to 20 and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Johann Doesn't work. Shadow still cliped by AppBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add to `Box` this code `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()`. `Box` cuts your shadow in your code

Example (I added there a white color to see the shadow better)

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = Color.White,
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TopAppBar(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            title = { Text("AppBar title") }
        )
    }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thats works! Thank you. But default shadow is very hard to detect visually. It's confusing.